# Concurrency Throttle

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

The below is a simple concurrency throttle and associated test.  It doesn't work as more often than not observe more concurrency than specified, but I'm not sure why?

```
[TestFixture]
public class ConcurrencyThrottleTests
{
    [Test]
    public void ThrottleTest()
    {
        var throttle = new ConcurrencyThrottle(2);
        var maxReg = new MaxRegister();
        var threadPool = new SmartThreadPool();

        var state = new DoWorkState {Throttle = throttle, MaxRegister = maxReg};
        var workItemResults = new List<IWaitableResult>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            workItemResults.Add(threadPool.QueueWorkItem(DoWork, state));

        SmartThreadPool.WaitAll(workItemResults.ToArray());

        Assert.IsTrue(maxReg.MaxValue <= 2);
    }

    public void DoWork(object state)
    {
        var doWorkState = (DoWorkState)state;

        doWorkState.Throttle.Enter();
        try
        {
            doWorkState.MaxRegister.Increment();

            Thread.Sleep(10);

        }
        finally
        {
            doWorkState.MaxRegister.Decrement();
            doWorkState.Throttle.Exit();
        }
    }

    public class DoWorkState
    {
        public IConcurrencyThrottle Throttle { get; set; }
        public MaxRegister MaxRegister { get; set; }
    }

    public class ConcurrencyThrottle : IConcurrencyThrottle
    {
        private readonly int _max;
        private readonly object _lock = new object();
        private readonly MaxRegister _register = new MaxRegister();

        public ConcurrencyThrottle(int max)
        {
            _max = max;
        }

        public void Exit()
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                _register.Decrement();

                Monitor.Pulse(_lock);
            }
        }

        public void Enter()
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                while (_register.CurrentValue == _max)
                    Monitor.Wait(_lock);

                _register.Increment();
            }
        }
    }

    public class MaxRegister
    {
        public int MaxValue { get; private set; }
        public int CurrentValue { get; private set; }

        public void Increment()
        {
            MaxValue = Math.Max(++CurrentValue, MaxValue);
        }

        public void Decrement()
        {
            CurrentValue--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For one thing, your shared MaxRegister class isn't thread-safe... are you sure that's not the problem?

Comment: I'm only calling it from the lock sections in the throttle so I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: But you've got concurrency=2 in the throttle - so there can be two threads both in the try block of DoWork at the same time, right? (I was referring to the calls to MaxRegister.Increment/Decrement from DoWork, not from ConcurrencyThrottle.)

Comment: Is that the actual problem, i.e. is it worth me writing it up as an answer? (You never told us how you were observing the problem, so it's not clear whether this is all there is...)

Comment: Yes, that was indeed the problem. The ConcurrencyThrottle is correct, the test was flawed because as you pointed out the MAxRegister wasn't thread safe. I was observing the problem via the failed assertion. Yes it is worth writing up the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that although the concurrency is limited to two, you're still using a non thread-safe object (a `MaxRegister`) within the throttled code:

```
doWorkState.Throttle.Enter();
try
{
    doWorkState.MaxRegister.Increment();
    Thread.Sleep(10);
}
finally
{
    doWorkState.MaxRegister.Decrement();
    doWorkState.Throttle.Exit();
}
```

`MaxRegister.Increment` and `MaxRegister.Decrement` involve no locking, and don't use the atomic `Interlocked` operations which would be required to make them safe.

Using `Interlocked.Decrement` would be enough in `MaxRegister.Decrement`, `Increment` is harder, as you've got two values. It's possibly that you could use `Interlocked.Increment` on `CurrentValue`, remember the result, and then atomically use `CompareExchange` to increase `MaxValue` if necessary. Or just use a lock for both operations :)

Note that in order to use `Interlocked`, you'd need to go away from using automatically implemented properties, as the interlocked methods have ref parameters.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, for starters in "ConcurrencyThrottle.Enter" you have :

```
while (_register.CurrentValue == _max)
```

Which would break if CurrentValue was greater than max, so maybe you should have :

```
while (_register.CurrentValue >= _max)
```

Secondly, you have

```
var maxReg = new MaxRegister();
```

in your ThrottleTest method, which you then assign and manipulate in your "state" variable - however, this variable is totally unrelated to the one that is declared in the ConcurrencyThrottle class.  So incrementing or decrementing the one in "doWorkState" has no effect what-so-ever on the one you are testing in "ConcurrencyThrottle.Enter".

I would be tempted to max ConcurrencyThrottle a singleton and have it like so :

```
public class ConcurrencyThrottle : IConcurrencyThrottle
{
    private int Max { get; set;}
    private static object _lock = new object();
    private static object _concurrencyLock = new object();
    public static MaxRegister Register { get; set; }
    private static volatile _Default;

    private ConcurrencyThrottle()
    {
        Register = new MaxRegister
        {
            CurrentValue = 0,
            MaxValue = 2
        };
    }

    public static ConcurrencyThrottle Default
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if(_Default == null)
                {
                    _Default = new ConcurrencyThrottle();
                }

                return_Default;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Enter() 
    { 
        lock (_concurrencyLock) 
        { 
            while (Register.CurrentValue == _max) 
                Monitor.Wait(_concurrencyLock); 

            Register.Increment(); 
        } 
    } 

    etc etc
```

This is obviously just a suggestion, but from what I can understand the MaxRegister in your ConcurrencyThrottle is unrelated to the one you are manipulating in "DoWork".

Hope that is of help, happy coding!
Cheers,
Chris.

Comment: As the ConcurrencyThrottle is correct _register.CurrentValue would never exceed _max, so I'm safe there.  The MaxRegister instance in the test and the MaxRegister instance in the ConcurrencyThrottle are separate by design.  The answer was simply that MaxRegister wasn't thread safe which meant the test was flawed as it could call MaxReigster on two threads simutaneously. See Mr Skeets answer above.  thanks.